# How do I rename the output file after Apify crawls?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, puppeteer, apify

I've searched through the Apify documentation and I wasn't able to find a way for me to set the output file name. Right now it's {INDEX}.json but can I have a custom name for each page that Apify crawls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you are running it locally. Then no, you cannot rename the JSON files created by `Apify.pushData()`. If you really need named results, you can use the Key-value store and save named JSON files there with `Apify.setValue()`. [Docs here](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/key-value-store#keyvaluestoresetvaluekey-value-options).